# How do I add customized devise error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
def create
        build_resource(sign_up_params.select{|k,v| v.present?})
        if Identity.identity_exists?(resource.email)
            # Prompt user to sign in with Facebook instead
            puts 'prompt user to sign in with facebook'
        else
            if resource.save
                # redirect_to_signup_finish / return ?  
            else 
                clean_up_passwords resource
            end
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render :json => { errors: resource.errors }, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
```

I have this code where if a user has signed up with Facebook with the same email as before, we prevent user from signing up again. Instead, we prompt them to login with facebook. We want to create a custom `resource.errors` that states this scenario. What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: fist I think you have a error with `respond_to` because always execute the same. You have to put inside of a `if` clause

Comment: `resource.errors.add(:email, 'Your email is already taken, please sign in with Facebook')` or `redirect to: new_sessions_path, flash: 'Your ...' and return`